# Add jar to Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

Here is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile file 'volley.jar'
}
```

When i try to build it this error appers:

```
Gradle: A problem occurred evaluating project ':Name'.
> No such property: file for class:     org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler
```

The same error appears if i try

```
gradle clean
```

in the project directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is typo at `compile files`

```
dependencies {
    compile files('volley.jar')
}
```

Comment: What causes the exception is the missing parentheses, which can't be omitted in this case (because they've already been omitted for `compile`). Nevertheless, it's important to use `files` rather than `file` here.

Comment: Do you mean you have same error `No such property: file`? It can be that your file is located at different from project root folder. E.g. `libs\volley.jar`.

Comment: I am still getting No such property file even after using this

Answer (score 0):

Now compile is changed to implementation since 2018

So

```
implementation files('volley.jar')
```